# Is it possible to generalize a Tuple property?

Tags: c#, oop

I'm looking for a way that a Tuple property can receive several tuples like `Tuple<int>`, `Tuple<string>`. The next code is an example that I'm trying to do:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual Tuple Condition
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class B: A
{
    public override Tuple<int, string> Condition
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I'd like to use the Condition property from A class, and use it in other classes like B and asign it an specific Tuple.

```
B b = new B();
B.Condition = Tuple.Create(2, "Bella");

A a = b;
a.Condition  // Here must show B.Condition
```

Comment: Exposing a Tuple as part of an API is seldom a good idea. What are you really trying to model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems with this approach:

1. `Tuple<T1, T2>` and `Tuple` are different classes, and method/property overrides don't support polymorphism in the return types.
2. Even if they did, `Tuple<T1, T2>` does not inherit from `Tuple`, so it wouldn't work anyway.

You would need to declare the `virtual` property to be of `object` and then just cast back and forth when needed. Alternatively, you may want to think about what your `Condition` property really represents; perhaps a custom class will prove more flexible than `Tuple`s.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't because the signature does not match.

The closest pattern you may consider is the following:

```
public class A
{
    public object Condition
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class B: A
{
    public void SetCondition(Tuple<int, string> condition)
    {
        base.Condition = condition;
    }
}
```

However, what you are looking for has a limited sense. In which way could you use a "generic" Tuple? At this point it's better to think to an object.